# RxJS: takeUntil ignores Subject event

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In the below code example the intention was to block the event from `second$` by emitting 1 to Subject `mid$`.

```js
import { Subject, timer } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, takeUntil, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const first$ = timer(1000);
const second$ = timer(2000);

const mid$ = new Subject();

first$.pipe(
  tap(() => { 
    mid$.next(1); 
  }),
  switchMap(() => second$.pipe(
    takeUntil(mid$),
    tap(() => console.log("MISSED!"))
  )),
).subscribe();


mid$.subscribe(() => console.log("RECEIVED"));
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lmcrpb?file=index.ts)

But it doesn't work for some reason as the console shows:

```
RECEIVED
MISSED!
```

I.e. the event emission in line `mid$.next(1);` isn't taken into account by `takeUntil(mid$)`

What is the logic here?

I noticed that if I replace line `mid$.next(1);` with `timer(0).subscribe(() => mid$.next(1));` it works as expected, but I'd like to know what is the proper way to handle such cases in RxJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work as intended like this

```js
const first$ = timer(1000);
const second$ = timer(2000);

const mid$ = new Subject();

first$.pipe(
  tap(() => { 
    mid$.next(1);
  }),
  switchMap(() => second$.pipe(
    takeUntil(mid$),
    tap(() => console.log("MISSED!"))
  )),
).subscribe();
```

because when `mid$.next(1);` is reached, the `switchMap`'s inner observable has not been created yet. So, `takeUntil` didn't subscribe to that `mid$` subject yet.

It works with `timer(0).subscribe(() => mid$.next(1));`(which is roughly the same as `setTimeout(() => mid$.next() , 0)`), because, in this case, when `mid$` emits, `switchMap` has already created the inner observable.

A quick way to solve this might involve using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject`, because the `BehaviorSubject` will send the last emitted value to new subscribers:

```js
const first$ = timer(1000);
const second$ = timer(2000);

const mid$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

first$.pipe(
  tap(() => { 
    mid$.next(1);
  }),
  switchMap(() => second$.pipe(
    // here, when `mid$` is subscribed, the subscriber will receive `1` 
    // and the entire inner observable will complete
    takeUntil(mid$),
    tap(() => console.log("MISSED!"))
  )),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks! With BehaviorSubject the takeUntil will react to the initial null as well, i.e. the second$ emission will be ignored even if we remove the line mid$.next(1). So we should use something like this instead to accept only non nulls: takeUntil(mid$.pipe(filter(x => x !== null)))

Comment: Btw, maybe you could recommend some good tutorial/book to learn the details of the observables creating, i.e. in which exact order the observables are created and subscribed?

Comment: @moon-413 There might be of course great materials on that topic, but I personally learnt a lot from reading the source code. You could also have a look at [ncjamieson.com](https://ncjamieson.com/) or [Ben Lesh's](https://medium.com/@benlesh) articles.

Answer (score 1):

takeUntil unsubscribes only the *next time* an observable emits. It does not know whether an observable has emitted previously.

```
const first$ = timer(1000);
const second$ = timer(2000);

const mid$ = new Subject();

first$.pipe(
  tap((first) => {
    console.log('first', first)
    mid$.next(1);
    console.log('first', first)
  }),
  switchMap(() => second$.pipe(
    tap((second) => console.log('second', second)),
    takeUntil(mid$), // Unsubscribing next time mid$ emits
    tap(() => console.log("MISSED!"))
  )),
).subscribe(second => console.log('final', second));


mid$.subscribe(() => console.log("RECEIVED"));
```

This will log

```
// 1s passes
first 0
RECEIVED
first 0
// 1s passes
second 0
MISSED!
final 0
```

This is what's going on:

One second passes. first$ emits and you switchMap to second$. Another second passes and second$ emits. Only now you tell it to unsubscribe after mid$ emits *the next time*. However mid$ has already emitted (and never emits again). If you replace second$ with interval(2000) you will see what I mean. "MISSED!" will be logged forever every 2s.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

If I send event to mid$ in between first$ and second$ emissions it works fine:
`timer(1500).subscribe(() => mid$.next(1));`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lmcrpb?file=index.ts)